# What's needed for typescript to get my definitions when using node.js require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I an using Visual Studio 2013 tools for Node.js with VS2013 Update 2.

I have the following code in a `util.ts` file:

```
var Util = function () {
    this.getSelectOption = function (elem, value) {
        var x = 99;
    }
module.exports = new Util();
```

and then in a `base.ts` file

```
// <reference path="../../Utils/util.ts" />
// <reference path="../../Utils/helpers.ts" />

var util = require('../../Utils/util.js');
```

When I hover over util then all I see is

```
(var) util: any
```

Can someone explain to me what might be wrong. I was expecting Typescript to be able to pick up the definition of the getSelectOption function?

Comment: What's your problem??? Whether u can't load the util.js??

Comment: util.js is loaded. My code works fine. But I cannot get statement completion with intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use TypeScript's `import`/`export` statements and not the standard commonjs pattern (`var` / `require`).

Also you will need to compile with the `--module commonjs` flag.

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

## Your code refactored

First file. Use a TypeScript container for your function. Like a module or a class. Also use `export`

```
   module Util {
       export function getSelectOption (elem, value) {
          var x = 99;
       }
   }
   export = Util;
```

other file (use `import`, no need for `.js` extension):

```
  import util = require('../../Utils/util');
```

## Reason

TypeScript supports both AMD + CommonJS targets with the *SAME* TypeScript code. And therefore extends the language to find a common ground to support them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Can you just confirm. If I do use the typescript import / export then does that work okay with node.js ? Also I actually have many more functions than just this.getSelectOption() does that mean I need to put export before each of these?  With my current implementation this is not needed. Thanks.